# Combine Facebook login and OAuth permissions

Tags: facebook, auth0

I'm using Auth0 to manage user signups with Facebook OAuth.

Currently, Facebook prompts me with 2 separate screens to get login info and the page permissions I need, as shown below.

Is there any way to configure Facebook to combine these 2 prompts into one?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to configure Facebook to combine these 2 prompts into one?

No, there is not.

The dialog is deliberately divided up in two parts, one asking for the "lesser" (mostly read) permissions, and a second one for the more "powerful" ones, that allow to manage stuff and create content.

---

Every user who has used a few apps that ask for such permissions before, should already be familiar with this process. (If your's aren't, then explain it to them, if necessary.)